# Consuming a Soap Webservice with a Console Application - C#

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

How do I make my console application call a asmx webservice(instead of using a class locally)

Comment: You want a web service to "call a console app" ? Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: I guess so, the console application should use the web service.

Comment: Here's an [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms464040%28v=office.14%29.aspx) that will teach you how to create both the web service and a client

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't really help!